# Azure search index storage size stops at 8MB

Tags: azure, search, indexing, limit, data-ingestion

I am trying to ingest a load of 13k json documents into azure search engine, but the index stops at around 6k documents without any error for the indexer and the index storage size is 7.96MB and it doesn't surpass this limit no matter what.

I have tried using smaller batches of 3k/indexer and after that 1k/indexer, but I got the same result.

In my json I have around 10 simple fields, and 20 complex fields (which have other nested complex fields, but up to level 5).

Do you have any idea if there is a limit per size for an index? And where I can set it up?

As SLA, I think we are using S1 plan (based on what limits we have - 50 indexers, and so on)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to help without seeing it, but I remember I faced a problem like this in the past. In my case, it was a problem of duplicating with the key field.

I also recommend you smaller batches (~500 documents)

PS: Take a look if your nested jsons are not too big (in case it's marked as retrievable).